# Is it possible to give a list a name from a parameter?

Tags: java, list, file, arraylist

If just started coding 2 months ago. After learning the basics of Java, I'm getting to my own projects now.

My question.
I'm reading in Excel-files from which I'm creating vocabulary-objects.
Those vocabularies are getting stored in an ArrayList.
I want to name my List like the file name.
I know how to get my filename, not to set it as listname, though.

If it isn't possible, can anyone think of an idea how I can distinguish my lists later on?

Comment: What do you mean you want to name your list? In what context, are you storing your list somehow like in a map? Maybe you can add some code to show us what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) structure to store pairs : filename and the list of files.
It could look like to `Map<String, List<File>> filesByFileName` where the key is the filename and the value is the list of files associated to.
Note that the `HashMap` (common implementation of `Map`)doesn't maintain a specific order of the entries but others like `LinkedHashMap` or `TreeMap` do.

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) is an Oracle tutorial about the Map interface.
By the way, favor `java.nio.file.Path` to `java.io.File` as much as possible.